# Confirmation on sort, order and min/max

Tags: support, documentation, sort

I'd like confirmation, if possible, that the following chart of sort types is correct:

```
sort       |orderable|min/max |min/max type
------------------------------------------
activity   |   yes   |  yes   | timestamp
views      |   yes   |  yes   | number
creation   |   yes   |  yes   | timestamp
votes      |   yes   |  yes   | number
votes*     |    no   |   no   |
active     |    no   |   no   |
featured   |    no   |   no   |
hot        |    no   |   no   |
newest     |    no   |   no   |
week       |    no   |   no   |
month      |    no   |   no   |
popular    |   yes   |  yes   | number
name       |   yes   |  yes   | string
reputation |   yes   |  yes   | number
added      |   yes   |  yes   | timestamp

* = for /questions, /questions/unanswered and /questions/tagged/{tags}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks correct to me.